# How can I remove all whitespace except one between words in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['AB CD', 'EF  GH', 'IJ   KL', 'MNO P', 'Q   RS']})

         a
0    AB CD
1   EF  GH
2  IJ   KL
3    MNO P
4   Q   RS
```

I want to remove all whitespace between words except for one. How can I do this?

resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
       a
0  AB CD
1  EF GH
2  IJ KL
3  MNO P
4   Q RS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `str.split()` with `agg(" ".join)`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['AB CD', 'EF  GH', 'IJ   KL', 'MNO P', 'Q   RS']})
df['a'] = df['a'].str.split().agg(" ".join)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       a
0  AB CD
1  EF GH
2  IJ KL
3  MNO P
4   Q RS
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
 import re
 df["a"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(' +', ' ', x))
```